# Is it possible to return a variable inside a include() in php function?

Tags: php

I have a function like this

```
function test()
{
    include("test.php");
}

echo test();
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
//echo 'test1';
return 'test2';
?>
```

`echo 'test1'` works but  `return 'test2'` not works.

for me return nothing.

Comment: You're not returning anything from your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you would also need to return that value from the function:

```
function test()
{
    return include("test.php");
}

echo test();
```